# android java accent coming broken

Tags: java, android

I'm making a request in an api, in the api every accent comes right `"Téstâoâo"`
however, when setting the TextView it is in the following form `TÃCstãÇoãCo`

Here's the code:

Request:

```
   public static Single<List<PojoRequestLocalizadorPlaca>> requestVistoriasPlaca(Context context, String placa, String tokenEmpresa){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    String url = Preferencias.apiv3Link +
            "vistorias/busca-por-placa/" +
            tokenEmpresa + "/" + placa + "/tes";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET,
        url,
        future,
        future
    );

    queue.add(request);

    return Single
            .fromFuture(future, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map(response -> {
                Type pojoRequestLocalizadorPlacaList = new TypeToken<List<PojoRequestLocalizadorPlaca>>(){}.getType();
                List<PojoRequestLocalizadorPlaca> vistoriasLocalizadas = new Gson().fromJson(response, pojoRequestLocalizadorPlacaList);
                return vistoriasLocalizadas;
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Part of setting the textView:

```
   TextView questionario = convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionarioLocalizaPlaca);
    questionario.setText(vistoria.getQuestionario());
```

how do I not come broken the words with accent of the request?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the encoding of the response

```
byte[] bytes = response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
String responseUtf8 = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```